# SELECT CON IF Y AÑADA UN VALOR

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda al momento de realizar la estructura un select con un if.

Tengo una tabla 'Escuela' , que tiene 3 columnas, ID, dirección y zona.

Otra tabla llamada 'zona', con las columnas Id, nombre.

Y una tercera tabla 'Dirección', con las columnas id, nombre.

El **select busca en la tabla 'Escuela'** en la columna **'Direccion'**, si el registro tiene algún valor en la columna **'Dirección'** entonces que busque ese valor en la tabla **direccion , igualandolo por el ID de la tabla Direccion**, y regrese el valor del nombre de la direccion y que añada una nueva columna diciendo de donde fue por ejemplo, la columna origen 'Tabla Dirección'.

En caso de que no encuentre registros que busque por la columna 'zona' en la tabla 'zona', lo busque por el ID, regrese el nombre y de la misma manera añadan el valor del origen 'Tabla Zona'

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo con una join.

```
select a.id, b.nombre from escuela a inner join direccion b on a.id=b.id
```

Pero me hace falta hacer un if para buscarlo en la otra tabla en caso de que no lo encuentre, y añadir el origen.

Espero y me puedan apoyar.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Aquí hay mucha gente que podrá ayudarte, pero hace falta un punto de partida de tu parte, que eres el interesado en aprender primero y en resolver el problema segundo. Entonces ¿qué has investigado, qué intento de solución tienes escrito, qué dificultades encuentras en el código? Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/174050/edit) agregando esos detalles y recibirás ayuda más pronto. Gracias.

Comment: Lo que te hace falta es hacer `LEFT JOINS` a las dos tablas secundarias. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede resolver usando IFNULL e IF:

```
SELECT
e.id,
IFNULL(z.nombre,
       IFNULL(d.nombre,'SIN DATOS')) nombre,
IF(z.nombre IS NULL,
   IF(d.nombre IS NULL,
      'SIN DATOS',
      'DESDE TABLA DIRECCION'),
   'DESDE TABLA ZONA') origen
FROM escuela e
LEFT JOIN zona z ON e.zona=z.id
LEFT JOIN direccion d ON e.direccion=d.id;
```

Hice un fiddle para que lo veas en funcionamiento: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a97b4/3/0

Creé 3 tablas y les puse algunos datos para cubrir todas las posibilidades:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `escuela` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` int(11),
  `zona` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `escuela` (`id`, `direccion`, `zona`) VALUES
  (0, 0, NULL),
  (1, NULL, 0),
  (2, 1, 1),
  (3, NULL, NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zona` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `zona` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES
  (0, 'Zona Cero'),
  (1, 'Zona Uno');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `direccion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `direccion` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES
  (0, 'Dir. Cero'),
  (1, 'Dir. Uno');
```

Lo que hace mi consulta es lo siguiente:
Conecta las 3 tablas usando los códigos de dirección y zona de la tabla escuela.
Las posibilidades son: existen valores sólo en Dirección; existen sólo en Zona; existen en las dos; no existen en ninguna de las dos.
Por eso empiezo con IFNULL. ISNULL intenta devolver el valor del campo que se le pasa como parámetro, pero si detecta que es un NULL, entonces devuelve el valor indicado en el segundo parámetro.
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULL,'SEGUNDO PARAMETRO');
```

Devolverá 'SEGUNDO PARAMETRO'

```
SELECT IFNULL('PRIMER PARAMETRO','SEGUNDO PARAMETRO');
```

Devolverá 'PRIMER PARAMETRO'

Con ésto ya resolvemos qué nombre traer. Será el de ZONA si ahí no es NULL, o el de DIRECCION si en ZONA es NULL pero en DIRECCION no lo es, o dirá 'SIN DATOS' si es NULL en las dos tablas.

Por otro lado, uso IF para decir desde dónde se trajo información.
IF es más parecido al IF tradicional de cualquier lenguaje de programación.
Evalúa una condición (primer parámetro). Si resulta verdadera, devuelve el segundo parámetro (lo que haría el THEN en muchos lenguajes), y si resulta falsa devuelve el tercero (lo que haría el ELSE en muchos lenguajes).

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT IF(TRUE,'PRIMERO','SEGUNDO');
```

devuelve 'PRIMERO'

```
SELECT IF(FALSE,'PRIMERO','SEGUNDO');
```

devuelve 'SEGUNDO'

Así es que para mostrar el origen de datos evalúa si zona.nombre es NULL. Si lo es, entonces evalúa si direccion.nombre es NULL. Si lo es (o sea que los dos IF se fueron por el THEN, o sea que los dos son NULL) entonces devuelve 'SIN DATOS'
Si zona.nombre es NULL pero direccion.nombre no lo es, entonces se va por el primer THEN y por el segundo ELSE, y devuelve 'DESDE TABLA DIRECCION'
Si zona.nombre NO ES NULL, entonces se va directamente por el primer ELSE, y devuelve 'DESDE TABLA ZONA'

El órden en el que evalúes ésta última sección es importante, porque en mi ejemplo SI HAY DATOS EN LAS DOS TABLAS TRAERÁ EL NOMBRE DE ZONA Y DIRÁ QUE ES DESDE LA TABLA ZONA.

Si para tu caso es preferible que, de haber datos en las dos tablas, devuelva el de DIRECCION, entonces deberías invertir los IFNULL y los IF

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada necesitas tener un punto de partida y creo que ese punto es el id de la escuela, teniendo eso podremos realizar lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Zona INT = 0;
DECLARE @Direccion INT = 0;

SET @Zona = (Select Zona from Escuela where id = @idescuela)
SET @Direccion = (Select Direccion from Escuela where id = @idescuela)

IF @Zona <> 0
BEGIN
   Select Nombre from Escuela inner join Zona on Zona.id = Escuela.Zona where Escuela.id = @idescuela
END
IF @Direccion <> 0
BEGIN
   Select Nombre from Escuela inner join Direccion on Direccion.id = Escuela.Direccion where Escuela.id = @idescuela 
END
```

Con eso puedes partir, crear un stored procedure que reciba como parametro el id de la escuela y en base a eso traes los datos.

espero y te haya servido mi opinion, y espero haber entendido tu problema.

Saludos.